# Excel - VBA - Search Array Value in Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro, part of which loops through an array of defined strings and finds them in column A of the worksheet.

This works perfectly fine if all of the strings of the array exist in column A, but falls over if the string does not exist.

I have struggled with a simple if statement that would help me out. If array value is not found, move next

```
For iArow = 0 To UBound(MyArray) - 1
    iRow = Range("A:A").Find(MyArray(iArow), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    Range("D" & iRow).ClearContents
    Range("I" & iRow).ClearContents
    Rows(iRow + 1).Insert
    Rows(iRow).Insert 
Next iArow
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dows that help?

```
For iArow = 0 To UBound(myArray) - 1
    Set Rng = Range("A:A").Find(myArray(iArow), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        iRow = Rng.Row
        Range("D" & iRow).ClearContents
        Range("I" & iRow).ClearContents
        Rows(iRow + 1).Insert
        Rows(iRow).Insert
    End If
Next iArow
```

Comment: Works a treat thanks.  But can you explain it to me!  It is like you are using a double negative to make a positive in the if statement to allow me to step through the statement if the array value is found.  Rng is set to the value of my array, that is fine.  But then ----- "If NOT Rng is NOTHING Then"   Am I reading that right?

Comment: `Nothing` is a keyword indicating that an object has no value. As there is no keyword `Anything` you have to use the double negation.

Comment: `Nothing` is a special value in vba. `Range.Find()` returns that value 'Nothing' when it does not find a match, and that's what Fratyx is checking in is if statement.